# UDP socket flushed. What are the limitations? When it blocks?

Tags: networking, udp

I plan to send high amount of data through UDP (video streaming), and I thought in a system that requires to detect when an interface has reached maximum upload bandwith.

I know that when I flush the output data in a socket it blocks until the buffer is emptied, but, why is the socket blocked? Sending more than the upload bandwith is one of those limitations? I mean, for example, I send instantly 100 Kb of data through a socket; having an upload speed of 10 Kb/s will make the socket block during 10 seconds? Or will it flush to another interface (Let's say, the router) and it will return altough the data was not sent to the Internet?

Remember that we are talking about UDP, so no ACKs.

Comment: The socket is blocked so that other threads/processes cannot interact with the socket and change its state while its in the middle of the operation. since a flush is an asynchronous operation, there is always the possiblility that another operation on that socket may begin while the flush is occuring, which would corrupt the data being sent. The mutex shoudl release as soon as the flush is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Your server bandwith and router bandwidth. Your server will be sending data as fast as it can put it on the wire of it's interface (UDP blocks, when socket buffer on server is full).

As far as I know, router will be droping excess packets (how exactly they will be selected depends on router OS) once it's buffers are full. Your application needs to deal properly with lost packets or implement some logic to control packet flow (there is no feedback in case of lost packets - UDP is **unreliable** transport).

[SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCTP) may be better alternative if it is acceptable option.

Comment: You opened a new world to me with SCTP. I've read about multihoming and I'm a bit impressed. So, using SCTP it will send the data through a different device automatically each time if the device can't support it? So I don't have to program a manual "device selector"? I just `send()` the data like I do with TCP or UDP and it will do the rest? (Obviously it will need some configuration, but that's minimal I suppose).

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález, I wouldn't expect miracles, but SCTP gained some foothold on different OSes, so it may be worth to try. I have too litle real experience with it to be aware of possible cavets.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález, it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342617/sctp-multihoming

Comment: yes, just sent a message to this guy via Google+ a while ago to ask some things if he don't mind. Thank you for everything! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the bandwidth is of 10Kb/s between you and your router, the socket will indeed be blocked for some time, the time to send the electric signals to the "next hop" device. If it is your Internet connection that is limited to 10Kb/s out, your socket will be freed pretty quickly but the router will have to deal with the next peer itself, so its socket will be busy while yours is emptied.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. For TCP, the OS will never send more data than agreed to, until it receives an ACK. For UDP, there are no ACKs, no flow control, no send windows; the OS will send as much as it possibly can fit through the pipe, or in fact as much as the CPU can process (dropping extra packets).

Comment: @grawity Still, when using UDP one of the limiting factors is the bandwidth and if it is capped to 10Kb/s it should make the socket less, well... usable. TBH I mainly encountered this behavior on a specific BSD distro I worked on at work, might not apply to everything. About the "not entirely correct" part, were you referring to UDP ? If my memory serves me right, a remote host _MAY_ answer to a UDP packet with an ICMP unreachable, can't it ?

Comment: Yes, but that's an error condition, the sender is not expected to _wait_ for it, as opposed to TCP ACKs.

Comment: I completely agree that was not what I intended to say. I will modify the answer to reflect that better.